# How to get Folder ID while creating a new folder in Google Drive using API

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a subfolder in google drive....I have created the main folder using API...Studying the Drive Api documentation I learned that to create a subfolder I need to specify the Main folder ID..But I couldn't find a way to get folder ID...

My question is , how to get Folder ID while creating a new folder in Google Drive using API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a file or create a directory you use [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) If successful, this method returns a [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) in the response body.

If you check the return of your insert you will find id which is the id of the file or directory that you just created.  You can then use this as the parent for your new directory.

**Code directly from the documentation:**

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
request.Upload();
File file = request.ResponseBody;    
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

Comment: Is there anything similar for v3?

Comment: V3 should be the same.   [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Yes, found it, we need to include Id in the request to get it in the response.